# PHP - how do I get back a (jquery) looped array from a query string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, get

Hey I am still new to PHP and am creating a form, in the form I have an array that is created and looped from JQuery. So initially there is only 1 input field in the form but the user can create up to 5 input fields. And if the form fails then I want to send back the users input so they don't have to refill them in. But nothing gets sent back and in the query string it just has sent back "kname=Array". Then form resets it back to 1 input field even if they had extended it to 5.

here is the html:

```
<label for="names" id="name"> Names: 
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="names" required value="<?php if 
(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] !== '') {echo $_GET['name'];} ?>"> 
</label>
<span id="warning"></span>
<button id="morenames">ADD MORE NAMES</button>
```

here is how I get and then send it back via the PHP

getting

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] !== '') {

    $vName= $_POST['name'];
    $allnames = '';

    foreach ($vName as $vNames) {
        $allnames .= $vNames. ' ';
    }

    if (filter_var($allnames , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === null) {
        $vValidation++;
    } 
} else {
    $vValidation++;
}
```

sending it back if it fails validation

```
$querystring = "kname=$vName";
$querystring .= "&";
$querystring .= "ksurname=$vSurname";
$querystring .= "&";
$querystring .= "kvalidation=failed";

header('Location: questionaire.php?' . $querystring );
exit();
```

JQuery code (i got this from someone else on stack overflow on side note when i click enter it also deletes the row is it possible to remove this so that only when they click the delete button it deletes?)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5;
    var wrapper         = $("#name");
    var add_button      = $("#morenames");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input name="name[]" class="names" required style="margin-bottom:5px;"><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click","#delete", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[what i put in the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKJjW.jpg)

what i put in
what gets put out

[What happens when validation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7FI.jpg)

Comment: And where are those loops?

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't create multiple input fields. `$querystring = "kname=$vName";` forces the Array in `$vName` to a string, resulting in `kname=Array`. You need a loop in your PHP code that iterates over $vName and outputs multiple `<input>` fields.

Comment: appologies i took the wrong part of code @ponury-kostek , i now corrected it so it got the foreach loop my appologies

Comment: sorry i updated my post could you help explain a bit on how to do that exactly and where i should do it @ChrisG?

Comment: You need to add a loop to the code in the first snippet, the HTML/PHP one.

Comment: What is excatly your probleme ? putting the values in the url or getting values from url in your JS code ?

Comment: apologies i'm not quite understand how to do is it possible if you able or have time to give me an example (or know of a place i can read up on this and examples etc) again i deeply apologize, if not ill just play around a bit more and do a lot more research, thanks in advance @ChrisG

Comment: @segito10 problem is getting it the array items into the query string so it shows an array not just "kname=Array" and then getting that from the query string back into the form (and create enough inputs via jquery if they filled in more then one input)

Comment: In your PHP code, validate the array. If it fails validation, use PHP to output the form, based on the array. You don't need to redirect. If you must do it via redirection, store the array of names in $_SESSION and in `questionaire.php`, use that to output an `<input>` for each name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the get params directly on inputs ike this :

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="names" required value="<?php if 
(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] !== '') {echo $_GET['name'];} ?>">
```

but this taking the params from the url then create your inputs from js as follow

```
var max_fields = 5;
var wrapper = $("#name");
var add_button = $("#morenames");
var x = 1;

// init inputs
init();

$(add_button).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input name="name[]" class="names" required style="margin-bottom:5px;"><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>'); //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", "#delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

function init() {
    var names_p = getUrlVars();
    console.log(names_p);
    Object.keys(names_p).forEach(function (key) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append(`<div><input name="name[]" class="names" value="${names_p[key]}" required style="margin-bottom:5px;"><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>`); //add input box

    })
}
```

Your html becomes :

```
<label for="names" id="name"> Names: 
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="names" required value=""> 
</label>
<span id="warning"></span>
<button id="morenames">ADD MORE NAMES</button
```

**Full Code :**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] !== '') {
    $vNameas= $_GET['name'];
    foreach ($vNameas as $vName) {
        $allnames .= $vName. ' ';
    }
    $querystring = "kname=" . implode ( "_" , $vNameas );
    header('Location: ?' . $querystring );
    exit();
}
?>
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="names" id="name"> Names:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="names" required value="">
    </label>
    <span id="warning"></span>
    <button id="morenames" type="button">ADD MORE NAMES</button>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var max_fields = 5;
    var wrapper = $("#name");
    var add_button = $("#morenames");
    var x = 1;
    // init inputs
    init();
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input name="name[]" class="names" required style="margin-bottom:5px;"><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>');
            //add input box
        }
        else {
            alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    }
                       );
    $(wrapper).on("click", "#delete", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    }
                 );
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {
        };
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
            if(key === 'kname') vars[key] = value;
        }
                                                );
        return vars;
    }
    function init() {
        var names_p = getUrlVars();
        console.log(names_p);
        if( names_p['kname']) {
            names_p['kname'].split('_').forEach(function (key) {
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append(`<div><input name="name[]" class="names" value="${key}" required style="margin-bottom:5px;"><button id="delete">Delete</button></div>`);
                                  console.log(key);
            }
                                               )
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, appologies for late reply but the internet went down (wohoo! :( ). unfortunately this code works and doesnt, i see that now it creates inputs however it looks like erm the first input is empty, the second has "Array" inputed in third input is empty, fourth input says "failed" and the fifth input doesnt show anything, (for my test i put the names: bob, smith, joe, harry, larry). I wish i could send a photo that may make it easier to see what i mean is thereanything to change to help this to make it work @segito10

Comment: ok upate your post with your new code and put a screenshot for me to understand better

Comment: sorry internet troubles ... but here i got the images uploaded sorry for late reply @segito10 heres what i put in and what i got back

Comment: if i create a concatinated new vairable just to pass through the querystring `$nametogetbackinquerystring .= $vNames . '_';` through the loop and the put in query string i get the response of Name=Arraya_b_c_d_e (the items from the array but still show up like the image i showed in the question @segito10

Comment: @Meitie you put the parameter in $vName= $_POST['name']; that's why you have "array" in the string and you can't send the array like that as a query string . What you can do is :
- format the array in a query parameter `kname=implode ( "_'' , $vName )`
- and modify the js function in order to get only the kname param by putting a condition in getUrlVars function like `if(key === 'vName') vars[key] = value;`
- in your init function `names_p[vName].split('_').forEach` instead of `Object.keys(names_p)` and `"${key}` instead of `${names_p[key]}`

Comment: hey @segito10 um so when i add the `"${key}` and the `kname=implode ( "_'' , $vName )` it then code still works ( although the word "array" still shows up in the query string `?kname=implode%20(%20"_%27%27%20,%20Array%20)` like that, however when I add the `if(key === 'vName') vars[key] = value;` and replace `Object.keys(names_p).forEach` with `names_p[vName].split('_').forEach` it clashes with the other javascript making me not able to add more input fields

Comment: also id like to thank you so much for helping me @segito10

Comment: welcome, but don't put the implode in the string it is a function formating your array to a sting with separators in your case you have to do like `$querystring = "kname=". implode ( "_'' , $vName );`

Comment: hey, my problem still persists and i really cant figure out, when i replace the `Object.keys(name_p).foreach` with `names_p[vName].split('_').foreach` it deactivates the add more button and then the add more button becomes a simple button that will submit the form instead @segito10 is there anyway to fix this ? i think this may be biggest problem as to maybe why the code wont work?

Comment: otherwise not in the php code i am able to put the array into the query string as `kname=tom_harry_larry` so that code works

Comment: @Meitie I have edited my answer adding a `Full Code` section there you can find the edits

Comment: thanks alot man i see where you put the stuff that kinda makes more sense to me thanks, just only issue i see if i fill 10 names in and then refresh the original input gets empty and the 5 are put into the inputs below. otherwise I thank you so much for the help and time you have given me <3